# `cd` command not working after update

Tags: ubuntu

My system manager just updated my Ubuntu machine and now my `cd` command does not work --I know, it sounds weird:

```
(base) dahl@jh125:~$ ls
anaconda3              Desktop      Music        public_html      Templates
appl                   Documents    Pictures     R                test 
'#. bash aliases#'     Downloads    Public       snap             test_box
(base) dahl@jh125:~$ cd Desktop/
bash: cd: !*: No such file or directory
Desktop/
(base) dahl@jh125:~$ cd Desktop
bash: cd: !*: No such file or directory
Desktop
```

I don't have `sudo` privileges, but still I would like to know what it's going on before reaching my already overbooked system manager, thanks!

Comment: Do you have `cd` aliased to something?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't; indeed, I can check. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If not an alias, maybe a shell function. What is the output of `type -a cd`?

Comment: `cd` is a bash builtin, so it should always be available (if not masked by an alias or function). What is in this `'#. bash aliases#'` file or directory? That looks suspicious in this context.

Comment: So the `cd` works (the cd error output matches what you would get for a cd to a directory that doesn't exist), it's just trying to cd to `!*` for some reason.

Comment: Can you also put the output of an `ls -l` as well as `cd /`?

Comment: It seems like the `'#. bash aliases#'` file has an alias I was unaware of: `alias cd='cd \!*;echo $cwd'`. It also explains why it is printing the extra line after the error message.